# ip command equivalent to `ifconfig lo x.x.x.x up`

Tags: ifconfig, loopback, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to set bind loopback to an IP address with `ip link set lo 10.254.254.254 up` but keep getting the error `Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "10.254.254.254" is a garbage.`

I googled the error, but there isn't any consistency in the answers and nothing that I have tried has helped.

Before I was using ifconfig, which is now deprecated and used the command `ifconfig lo 10.254.254.254 up`. Am I correct that above lo command should do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all a garbage. It doesn't make sense to use `ip link` to add IP addresses. It's used to manage lower layer characteristics of the interface, such as name, MAC address, etc.

To set an IP address, you will use `ip address` instead.

```
ip address add <address>/<prefix> dev <interface>
```

For example:

```
ip a add 10.254.254.254/32 dev lo
```

Comment: Thank you @michael-hampton !
I couldn't find anywhere what the equivalent of that ifconfig command was using ip.